# How can I change the position of the hint in an editText?

Tags: android

I want to align my second hint(email) to match the position of the first one(nickname), and I can't seem to do it.
Please check my layout from this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJA8U.png)

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="347dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="20"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32999998">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/nickname"

        android:maxLength="21"
         />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<EditText
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="342dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.463"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.062"
    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    />
```

please note that I am a beginner in android, so take it easy on me.

Comment: Did you mean to use two different views for both?   If you want the bottom to look like the top it should be a `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` inside a `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`  not an `EditText`

Comment: Yeah just using the exact same setup (so you get the same styling) for both fields is the best way to go. You *could* try and style the `EditText` so its hint aligns with the Material component but honestly, that's brittle and making a lot of work for yourself. You'd need to test it on all kinds of screen sizes at different system font size settings just make sure it looks right, and if they update the Material styling, you'll have to fix it again. Way easier to use the tools out of the box and avoid doing anything "clever" with the UI unless you need to - speaking from experience here!

Comment: In simple words, add left padding to the Email EditText.